# Confused about error with srand() function

Tags: srand

I'm trying to use the srand function, but I keep getting the error

> "Called object of type 'int' is not a function or function pointer".

Here is how I'm using it:

```
 srand(time(NULL));
```

Don't use the rand generator often, so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are using `int srand` as a variable somewhere in your code in the same scope where you are calling `srand(time(NULL));`

This clearly leads to an ambiguity.

Solution: Change the variable name.